# How-to emit and parse raw binary data using yaml-cpp

Tags: yaml-cpp

Is it possible to emit and read(parse) binary data(image, file etc)? 
Like this is shown here: 
http://yaml.org/type/binary.html
How can I do this in yaml-cpp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of [revision 425](http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/source/detail?r=425), yes! (for emitting)

```
YAML::Emitter emitter;
emitter << YAML::Binary("Hello, World!", 13);
std::cout << emitter.c_str();
```

outputs

```
--- !!binary "SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ=="
```

The syntax is

```
YAML::Binary(const char *bytes, std::size_t size);
```

I wasn't sure how to pass the byte array: `char` isn't necessarily one byte, so I'm not sure how portable the algorithm is. What format is your byte array typically in?

(The problem is that `uint8_t` isn't standard C++ yet, so I'm a little worried about using it.)

As for parsing, `yaml-cpp` will certainly parse the data as a string, but there's no decoding algorithm yet.

Comment: Is there a way to do it *without* base64 encoding first?  I'd like users to be able to specify short binary strings without going through those extra steps

Comment: @endolith, what do you mean "without base64 encoding"? Can you give an example? (Maybe open a new question to ask?)

Comment: `SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==` is base64 encoded. I'd like it to be encoded more like `48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57 6f 72 6c 64 21`

Comment: @endolith: Nevermind.  The `!!binary` tag requires base64, but you can define your own tags and interpret them however you want.  I used `add_implicit_resolver` to handle the hex strings without any tag at all.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is answered how to read/parse binary data from a yaml file with the yaml-cpp library.

This answer assumes that you are able to load a YAML::Node node object from a yaml file - explained in the yaml-cpp tutorials: https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial).

The code to parse binary data from a yaml node is:

```
YAML::Binary binary = node.as<YAML::Binary>();
const unsigned char * data = binary.data();
std::size_t size = binary.size();
```

Then you have an array of bytes "data" with a known size "size".